# Make derived class follow trait

Tags: c++, type-traits

Suppose I have a base class

```
class Base {};
```

`std::is_trivial<Base>::value` is `true`. Is there a way to force all classes that are derived from `Base` to also be trivial?

In other words, how can I modify `Base` so that this causes a compilation error?

```
class Derived : public Base {
    Derived() {}
};
```

Comment: Are you specifically asking about the use of `private` inheritance?

Comment: IMO this is impossible. On the other hand, it might be possible if you lower your requirements. Maybe check that a type derived from `Base` and used in a specific function is trivial. Why exactly do you need that trait to be true?

Comment: I think YSC is correct.  I was thinking you could use CRTP but you couldn't check if the derived class is trivial as it is not complete inside the base class.

Comment: @NathanOliver And you couldn't enforce the writer of the child class to cheat or misuse the CRTP anyway.

Comment: Given that trivial classes cannot be polymorphic, why do you care?

Comment: This is for a weird custom tool that abuses classes a little... Seems like it is impossible anyway so I'll just have the tool check whether Clang actually generated a constructor or not, and then give an error if it did.

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't write a constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert> 
struct A {
    int m;
};

struct B : A{
    B() {}
};

struct C : A{
    C() = default;
};

int main() 
{
    assert( std::is_trivial<A>{});
    assert(!std::is_trivial<B>{});
    assert( std::is_trivial<C>{});
}
```

To do the "enforce" part is more tricky, you can put a contraint, but using CRTP.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert> 

template<class D>
struct A {
    int m;
    static void enforce(){static_assert(std::is_trivial<D>{},"");}
};

/*struct B : A<B>{
    B() {}
};*/

struct C : A<C>{
    C() = default;
};

int main() 
{
//    assert( std::is_trivial<A>{});
//    assert(!std::is_trivial<B>{});
    assert( std::is_trivial<C>{});

}
```